# Is Read-only property available in tree node in C#?

Tags: c#, readonly, tree-nodes

How to set tree node 'read only' in windows C#?  Should not us disable, default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `TreeView.LabelEdit` property to False

Comment: only a particular node, not tree itself!!

Comment: You can cancel all the Edits, using Node.EndEdit(false).